# App Store Can't See Repo I have Admin Permissions To

Tags: git, azure-devops, visual-studio-app-center

I'm trying to connect a Azure git repository to my App Center for automated builds. For some reason, the repository doesn't show up, despite the fact that I have administrator access to the repository. In the organization settings for the organization settings for the repository, my access level is "Visual Studio Professional subscription", not "Stakeholder". I'm confused as to why I wouldn't see it in the App Center.

[image: I can't see the repository in App Center]

[image: I have the Visual Studio Professional subscription access level]

[image: I have admin rights to the repository]

[image: I have every "allow" permission to the repository.]

Comment: First, did you change the user to `basic` permission under the organization Settings? Also, you should check under Project Settings--> Repos--> Repositories--> give the allow permission under the security of the related repos.

Comment: Like I said, I literally have all the permissions except for bypassing policies and force pushing. I'll attach a screenshot proving this. I fail to see why I should *need* basic permission settings, but I haven't done that yet. I'll have to see if someone managing our AD can do so.